# wordpress image uploads

Tags: wordpress, image-processing

I have created my own upload function for forms on my sites frontend. the images upload correctly, but in some cases a blank reference to the image with this as its path:  /USR/WWW/USERS//WP-CONTENT/BLOGS.DIR/2/FILES/ occurs in the media library. its seems as though the form uploads images but where there is no image to upload a blank reference is 'uploaded' instead. any ideas of what may be causing this? deleting these empty rows in the db does not affect the site, but seems like bad practice.

Comment: 1: Show us your code?
2: where should/are the images uploaded to?
3: When you say 'the images upload correctly' i assume you mean they go where they should RE: question2?
4: Assuming question 3, do the blank references only occur when there is no image set to be uploaded?

Assuming 4, it sounds like you haven't checked for the existance of the file at both ends (i.e uploader assumes a picture is coming its way).

If so, either throw in a little conditional, or set a default image.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Andrew Bolster, we need a bit more information to help you.

However, based on my own experience, it might be a problem with the filenames themselves. I found WordPress's own function for creating filenames, santize_file_name(), and that saved me a lot of trouble personally.

Check out the details here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_file_name